# Error in Converting varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-convert

I am trying to convert varchar to datetime, everything is ok when I use the convert function like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000', 120)
```

but when I try to declare a varchar parameter and pass it to the function, I encounter the error

```
declare @input varchar = '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, @input, 120)
```

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick: Declaring varchar without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length?CommentPosted=true). Try e.g. `SELECT @input` between your two lines to see what you've currently got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please specify the size while using a varchar.

`varchar = '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'` is `'2'` `--SELECT @input`

use

```
declare @input varchar(30) = '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, @input, 120)
```